# Index / Match Pulling in Different than Expected Content

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am examining web stats across a range of a year. Because I want the entire workbook to be dynamic depending on what months are chosen, I have put all of several year's worth of data on one worksheet.

Using the index / match combination I was able to this easily when years were split into multiple worksheets, not so much now.

Here are the two expressions.

Current month /year `=INDEX(DATA,MATCH(Data!A4,HEADERS,0),MATCH($B$3,MONTHS2013,0))`

Previous month /year `=INDEX(DATA,MATCH(Data!A4,HEADERS,0),MATCH($F$3,MONTHS2012,0))`

The problem is that with all the data on one worksheet, both formulas always default to the very first month cell. I've tried renaming the cells from both being July to 2012 July and 2013 July, but same thing. happens.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I've even tried going in and specifying the cell range instead of using cell range names.

Any thoughts?

(I should specify that the month dates are all on one row, though each has been given a unique name.)

Sorry.

DATA - Raw Data

Data!A4 - Unique Visitors

HEADERS - Data row names (i.e. Unique Visitors)

MONTHS2013, MONTHS2012 are both month ranges, though they are in the same row.

I'll make a 2 worksheet copy scaled down and link to it.

(add http:)//www.handyblues.org/images/WebReport.xlsx

Can't post more than two links, so broke it out.

I could really, really cuss for not trying that solution to begin with. There are some other pages that I'll be building dynamic graphs on, so really needed this solution to work. Thanks for pointing out the months issue, it now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your named ranges.

`MONTHS2013` is from N2:Z2 while your `DATA` is from B2:Z80

When you use match for the column number (in the index function), you are getting the value `8` from the match, since it starts in column N and matches in column U. Pick the 8th column in `DATA` and you get the value you were getting.

I would suggest keeping a single named range for the Months, starting at B2 and ending at Z2. You might also have to review all the named ranges you have in case there are more to be corrected.

Otherwise, you can use `HLOOKUP` with the syntax:

```
=HLOOKUP(B$3, Data!$2:$80, ROW()-2, FALSE)
```

And drag down (or right) as far as you need. I noticed that you are using the same `HEADERS` in both sheets, so that you can use `ROW()-2` to match the number of columns you need.